# UserProfileManager.Search(string[])

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

whats up?
Has anyone used the UserProfileManager.Search method? if I pass an array of strings it does an 'AND' or an 'OR' search?
Is it possible to do a 'Like' search using this function?
Thanks in advance, and happy holidays

Comment: Just found this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yardman/archive/2010/06/29/sharepoint-userprofilemanager-search-method-sample.aspx. I'm currently doing some concept testing to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to leverage search and SPQuery for a full text query, much more power.

You can then use this in conjuction with the UPM to get the user profile.

To use a the search engine use the code which I posted here (but change scope to people and map the fields if you need extra)

[Using SPQuery](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51714/define-search-scope-as-managed-property/52867#52867)

```
// Then get the user
UserProfile userProfileColleague = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(username);
```